# How to return an image using NEST

Tags: image, nest

It's my first time, I write a question here. I have this problem, when I use `Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString( 'base64')`, I still can't see the image on my response in postman. I hope you can help me with this problem. I receive a ArrayByte from the back, But when I try to send the image across nest, I see something like that:

```
�PNG

IHDR D���gAMA���asRGB���PLTELiq���F��A����<����U�(����"��5��D��>����F��8��3��!��#��B��C��C��E��H��?��B��#��'��#��%��"�U��$��'���!��G��(��'��3��E��?��I��G��L��J��K��Q��K��J��K����@��;��1��9��;��5��/��=��6��;��;��+��-��1��.��)������������������F�� ��$��$�� ��J��I������K��8��L��-����)��-��M��L������-������)��.��8�����������2��3��8��:��C�� ��F��0��"��5��>��5��<��'��,��(��+��;��$��D�������%����/��A��E��@��4��)��&��������.��A����?�������K��@��*��!��&��I��.����B����#�������������!��G��/��O��;��9��e��y���ٯ�����u�����b��E��H��D��&��#��E��"����5��%��J��L��H��K��M��9��<��A��1��8��<��0��+����$������߼�ϙ�М�֩�ԣ�Ă�̒��o��Q�޺����ʎ��w�ƅ�����Y����Ɔ��0��5��1��������������������ح��7�զ�����M�޺����������V��8�����~��P�͕����џ�����T�Ƈ����m�����]���۳#�jtRNS�� ��������%''�&3���3������ ���������+�������������������֛������(���Ό�����a���``��+������,��VY5eIDAT8�U�uXSQ���    ��������ww��±R���10�Al������8�^g�����{�=�� ���L�Ե{�NݻΚ��E�p�ع��];���m۹k{��Ii����v��u�������#��8�rO�$^��.�$��:��r�%��hcy��X�u ��4pX�Ma�f�.4��k�����;��h4V��Wx��5g��r����|���(9...٤��9�N�E�[   �hS;�<{�h���_�I��EjHU��' ��ޞ"��a��_�+W ��깷�G�>+HD�*� �QT\�pD������/���A���ܹ ���@o�<��CQy.��I�t&P����E�����b���j�e� ����X����V��)dε>�T>գ�JQ���Qvt����JNBw�7I��"%K�A��\�Ǭ*e{A� >�-��r�>�W�>(5'đ�� ���j�� +y��yq�,�$*C�XS�C$�AŹ����H%?�Q��(��uH�B��>P&������.S��z.�{E�>A�U������1�P�J%k/��B|� �lt|�D�RZ���F*���-��rK�����#*,ۤ���m[���b�!�(^�[��z�4O��O˶l�#|S�Y�J���8�]B׿$>��$��Y�/��-c64]�Ɋze�|�-�b!�+�n�hA'~�����,�=�Qm� (�otfS�S�8����rY\��K��5չ  ��j��n��2�r9��U�t�oŶ�D�մ٩C"�L��Ɍ��:qB��99�K�gfΰ�2gf�ϛ�������×6x���O�Q�/׸���1­IEND�B�
```

When I use the conversion I see this:

```
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.
```

This is my code on service:

```
async obtenerQR(pais: string, documento: string, apellido: string, nombre: string): Promise<Uint8Array> {
   // this.logger.log(`START obtenerQR con pais ${pais}, documento ${documento}, nombre ${nombre} y apellido ${apellido} `);
    const apiBaseUrl = this.configService.getValue('servicioCoreTokenDigital');
    const url = `${apiBaseUrl}/obtenerQR`;
   // this.logger.debug(`URL de CORE con el endpoint es: ${url}`);

    const body = { pais, documento, apellido, nombre };
    const response : string = await this.http.post(url, body);
    //response = Buffer.from(response)
    //let buff = new Buffer(new Uint8Array);
    //const responseBinary : string = await this.http.post(url, body);
       var base64data = Buffer.from(response, 'binary').toString('base64');
    const qr = Buffer.from(base64data, 'base64');
   // console.log("qr", qr);
    //const qrArray = new Uint8Array;
   // console.log("q`your text`rArray", qrArray);
  //  this.logger.log(`END obtenerQR con pais ${pais}, documento ${documento}, nombre ${nombre} y apellido ${apellido} `);
  
    return qr;
```